# sqlite clear cache

Tags: sqlite

how do you clear cache in sqlite?
I tried sending below commands but non succeeded.

```
PRAGMA default_cache_size = 0
PRAGMA cache_size = 0
```

Also, is there a good GUI (other than Sqlite Administrator) that I can execute more than one statements?

Comment: Why do you want to clear the cache?

Comment: @Martinv.Löwis: To benchmark dry-run performance most likely.

Comment: If you're doing this to measure the performance of complex queries (as I was), another option is to simply create a new (non-shared-memory) connection each time.

Answer (score 8):

Are you perhaps looking for the [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) statement?

Comment: I have a 6GiB SQLite database I want to run performance tests on. In my case it's way faster rebooting my system to clear the cached pages than running VACUUM.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (from [http://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches](https://web.archive.org/web/20120210065352/https://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches)):

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Way faster than VACUUMing a huge DB.